# PHP: How to access functions outside of namespace class that are in another class with no namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces

My main script has a namespace of "App".
I have imported another PHP script into my main script.

My main script thinks the function is part of App... when it's not. It's in the other PHP script.

How do I access functions that are outside of the namespace?

Comment: `\function_name()` http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First option is to import the namespace on that particular php file then you can alias; meaning u tell php that u will reference an imported class, interface, function, or constant with a shorter name. As of PHP 5.6 it's possible to import functions and constants. This requires a tweak to use the keyword syntax. To import a function:

```
<?php 

 use func Namespace\functionName;

 functionName();

?>
```